# Patching a perl cgi web application

Tags: perl, web-applications, patch

I've written a web cgi application in perl and before I start to distribute it to clients, I'd like to provide an option for future updates.

I would like to know what are the standard approaches for that using free Linux tools.
It is OK for the server to be stopped during updating.

Thank you,

Spasski

Comment: is your Perl program run as a mod_perl script? If so you may have to restart your web server when you update your script, or not if you are using a framework that detects script changes; either way you will have to restart if a module is changed. Are you using fastcgi? Then a quick-restart of your script is all that will be required. Are you using plain old CGI? Then no restart of web-server is required as your script is loaded and parsed on every request.

Comment: @PP - I am using plain old CGI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have separated code from configuration and data, then the easiest way is to tar/zip the new files and unpack them onto the existing installation. If you need to update the data files, then you could include a script that makes the necessary changes.

Take a look at th bugzilla upgrade guide. I've used this process many times without a hitch.

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/upgrade.html